# Problems with mariadb create trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, mariadb

I have 2 tables (**tasks - where adding new tasks with user phone and his company id and tenant_phones_comp - where i add only 2 col: user phone and user company id**) and i try to create a trigger at mariadb server. Trigger must insert row to **tenant_phones_comp** after inserted new line at **tasks** and if phone and company_id of that new task is not exists in **tenant_phones_comp** table insert them from new record in tasks. I have problem when i try to create triger. [example here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gmXjm5oH8ABrZtak4Ew5jm/0)

Comment: Can you please edit your question to add table definitions? It would make it much more readable I think.

Comment: described (edited) it

Comment: There is no or replace option in mysql https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html and not in mariadb until 10.1.4 https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-trigger/

Comment: Haven't problems with replace, all os working fine

Comment: Would you like to describe the problem you do have? Note the fiddle is mysql 5.7 and will never work there..